# MongoDB with Python on Google Colab - syntax error on $elemMatch

Tags: mongodb, google-colaboratory

I have installed MongoDB inside the Google Colab VM, created a database, loaded a table and running quite a few commands successfully.

When I try to run the following command

```
db.restaurants.find({grades : { $elemMatch:{"score":{$gt : 90}}}})
```

i get the following error:

```
File "<ipython-input-28-86e6fcc5b428>", line 1
    db.restaurants.find({grades : { $elemMatch:{"score":{$gt : 90}}}})
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have looked at the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#examples) but I cannot find what is wrong. In fact, I copied a similar command from the documentation itself

```
db.survey.find(
   { results: { $elemMatch: { product: "xyz" } } }
)
```

and I got the exact same error!!

```
File "<ipython-input-33-8cd8460d9613>", line 2
    { results: { $elemMatch: { product: "xyz" } } }
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Now I am thoroughly puzzled. While doing the cut-and-paste, I have taken the trouble to paste in notepad to remove the possibility of hidden, non-printing characters.

What could be the issue here? Please help with any suggestions.

EDITS :
I am using python and pymongo package and my [colab notebook is available here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1TPW9kOSCelWDk25XHS0daTi040J9Rq_o?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the JSON keys in **quotes** for python objects.

```
db.restaurants.find({"grades" : { "$elemMatch":{"score":{"$gt" : 90}}}})
```